# Sorting alphabetically in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do i make ActiveRecord to sort my movies title alphabetically when i click on a link in ruby on rails? Movies contains title with alphabets and others numbers. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  You typically will get a better response if you add some code that you've tried.  Please consider adding what you think should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing the details of your application, you could do something like the following for your migration file:

```
class CreateMovies < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :movies do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :description

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

And your model:

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

And your controller:

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @movies = if params[:sort_by] == "title" 
      Movie.order(:title)
    else
      Movie.all
    end
  end
end
```

And in your view:

```
<%= link_to "All Movies", movies_path %>
<%= link_to "Movies sorted alphabetially", movies_path(sort_by: "title") %>
```

Comment: Please accept the answer if you found this helpful. Otherwise please provide more information so we can offer further assistance

Comment: Yeah! That actually work @Greg Answer.